# Prove that a complex series diverges.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I am pretty rusty on convergence tricks. I want to check why the series

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+i},
$$

diverges. This is something like the harmonic series but for complex numbers. One way that I have in mind to prove it is that to show that either its real or imaginary part diverges. In fact the real part diverges, which is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^2+1},
$$

but I don't know how to prove this. I have tried by using the monotone convergence theorem for it's partial sums but couln't find a bound, and the comparison test but couldn't find a suitable series for which to compare.

Comment: $\frac{k}{k^2 + 1}$ will eventually be close to $\frac{1}{k}$. Do you know the convergence of $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$? How will it be related to your series?

Comment: I didn't knew the limit comparison test (LTC) given below. Certainly it is a cheap way to prove convergence/divergence just by looking at the limit you say, and the LTC can be applied directly.

Comment: You could also say that $\frac{k}{k^2+1}\geq \frac{k}{k^2+k}$ for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has, as $k \to \infty$, 
$$
 \frac{k}{k^2+1}= \frac1{k} \cdot\frac1{1+\frac1{k^2}} \sim \frac1{k}
$$ then, by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), the series $\displaystyle \sum \frac{k}{k^2+1}$ is divergent, thus the given complex series is divergent.

*Edit*. One may observe that your inital complex series is related to the digamma function $\psi:=\dfrac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}$. One may write, as $N \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^N \frac1{k+i}=\log N- \psi(1+i)+ \frac{\frac12+i}N+O\left( \frac1{N^2}\right),
> $$

the divergence is thus logarithmic.